# Connect to Oracle NOSQL KVLite from another host

Tags: oracle, nosql

Can I connect to Oracle NOSQL KVStore from another host just copy the files
from server's /user/security folder to this host?
NOSQL client already installed on the host machine.

More presizely:

KVLite runs under the VirtualBox. Host machine is Windows 11 machine.

Any help would be very appreciated.

TIA,
Andrew.